# Calculate difference between columns with same underlying name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df which compares the new and old data. Is there a way to calculate the difference between the old and new data? For generality, I don't want to sort the dataframe, but only compare root variables that have a prefix "_old" and "_new"

```
df
     apple_old      daily    banana_new    banana_tree   banana_old apple_new
0      5             3           4              2           10        6
```

```
for x in df.columns:
    if x.endswith("_old") and x.endswith("_new"):
        x = x.dif()
```

Expected Output; brackets are shown just for clarity

```
df_diff
     apple_diff(old-new)         banana_diff(old-new)       
0      -1       (5-6)                      6   (10-4)
```

Comment: What happens to `daily` and `banana_tree`? Also shouldn't `apply_diff` be `-1` since `apple_new` is 6 and `apple_old` is 5 and `5 - 6 = -1`?

Comment: since they don't have an "old" and "new" prefix they are irrelevant or can be saved in a separate df. I've amended the typo, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try creating a Multi-Index, then subtracting `old` from `new`.

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'apple_old': {0: 5}, 'daily': {0: 3}, 'banana_new': {0: 4},
                   'banana_tree': {0: 2}, 'banana_old': {0: 10},
                   'apple_new': {0: 6}})

# Creation of Multi-Index:
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
# Subtract old from new:
output_df = (df['old'] - df['new']).add_suffix('_diff')
# Display:
print(output_df)
```

```
   apple_diff  banana_diff
0          -1            6
```

---

Multi-Index with [`str.rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html)
and max split length `n=1` so multiple `_` are handled safely:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
```

```
    old   NaN    new   tree    old   new
  apple daily banana banana banana apple
0     5     3      4      2     10     6
```

Then selection:

```
df['old']

   apple  banana
0      5      10

df['new']

   banana  apple
0       4      6
```

Subtraction will align by columns. Then [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) to add the `_diff` to columns.

Comment: Thanks. Would this work if I have columns like "pear_tree_old"? I.e. with underscores elsewhere in the name, too?

Comment: Yes, I actually already thought of that so I updated to use `rsplit` with max split length `n=1` so `pear_tree_old` would become `pear_tree` and `old`